# Adjective to describe a good pilot

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes someone good at controlling a vehicle, i.e., means a very "skilled pilot"? Trying to avoid using the word "pilot", "driver", etc.

Comment: [**Dexterous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dexterous): *having the ability to perform a difficult action quickly and skilfully with the hands.*

Comment: Dexterous is too broad -- could be describing someone who's good at knitting or basketball but who has never entered a vehicle.

Comment: That's why it's a 'comment'. It was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The word is proficient, and hence, proficiency.

There are "driver proficiency" improvement programs.

There is a "pilot proficiency program" (https://www.faasafety.gov/WINGS/pub/learn_more.aspx).

Therefore, we would say, a proficient driver, a highly proficient pilot.

Just as we would say "English proficiency".

> pro•fi•cient (prəˈfɪʃ ənt)
>
> adj.
>
> 1. fully competent in any art, science, or subject; skilled: a proficient swimmer. n.
> 2. an expert. [1580–90; < Latin prōficient-, s. of prōficiēns, present participle of prōficere to advance, make progress] pro•fi′cien•cy
>    (-si) n. pro•fi′cient•ly, adv.
>
> Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K
> Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All
> rights reserved.

Answer (score 0):

*Ace* would be a good choice if you're looking to avoid *driver* or *pilot* as it can take their place without directly specifying the activity the person excells at.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ace)

> ace
>
> noun
>
> 2 *informal* A person who excels at a particular sport or other
> activity.
>
> ‘The motorcycle ace won a world title on the all-powerful Honda last
> year and then celebrated victory by signing for the all-powerless
> Yamaha.’

Of course, it is also listed as an adjective, but that would still require the use of *driver*, *pilot*, etc.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> *informal*  Very good.

> The site was first noticed by World War I ace pilot Gilbert Insall as
> he flew over a field where the chalky fill of ancient pits showed up
> as white spots. (The Henge Builders.  Pitts, Mike,    ACAD: Archaeology)

Though it seems to me that one could simply remove *pilot* from the above example and achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Remember, using the word ace to refer to piloting skills has the connotation specifically of military pilots who have shot down a certain number of enemy aircraft. When talking to other pilots, this will be the accepted definition. Aviator might be more of a complement rather than just pilot. But, there is no quantitative or qualitative connotation in that term. Therefore , Chesley Sullenberger is an accomplished aviator. But, he is not an ace pilot.

Comment: While I like the word "ace" I'm not looking to replace the noun. Even though it says ace can be an adjective, it seems to only make sense when modifying the word "pilot". Could I say "She's very ace" in the same way I might say "She's very dexterous"?

Comment: While it wouldn't have the same meaning as dextrous, _ace_ has been used this way - _Here, enjoy live music across the weekend, sports on the big screens, and some very *ace* happy hour specials, including $6 knock-off wines after 4pm each day_ (Guide to the Bars, Pubs, and Clubs of St Kilda).

Comment: Since _ace_ already indicates a high degree of skill, modification by _very_ seems superfluous in most situations in the same way _very excellent_ or _extremely top-notch_ would seem not to need the degree modifiers.